# Как биндить в input свойства с плавающей запятой в ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp-net-core-mvc

Есть свойство `decimal` которое биндится следующим образом `<input asp-for="ViewModel.Price">` в `*.cshtml` файле, однако при попытке задать значение с запятой/точкой то ловлю ошибку в `ValidateModel()`. Погуглил и понял, что это проблема самого ASP.NET, использовать всякие конверторы очень не хочется, есть какие-то наиболее простые способы?

Comment: Попробуйте поиграться с UseRequestLocalization в Startup.Configure

Comment: @PavelMayorov к сожалению не работает и ломает локализацию сайта при попытке переключиться на другой язык (не переключается т.к клиентская часть говорит что нахожусь в россии)

Comment: Так у вас есть переключаемая локализация сайта? А биндинг ломается во всех локализациях?

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, у меня переключается на русский или английский. Биндинг ломается при русской вне зависимости от разделителя (точка/запятая). Если язык английский то биндинг с точкой работает нормально (но не с запятой)